# Unable to insert records using Iterable Batch class

Tags: apex, batch, insert, record, iterable

I'm trying to create an Iterable Batch class for inserting records. I'm able to insert my records in my normal class. I have created the Batch class and am trying to call it my current class in the following manner:

```
   BatchReportsInsertion b = new BatchReportsInsertion(reportsToAdd);

   Database.executeBatch(b);
```

My Batch class is as follows:

```
global class BatchReportsInsertion implements Database.Batchable<Report__c> 
{

List<Report__c> batchList;



global BatchReportsInsertion (List<Report__c> reportList) 
{

  this.batchList = reportList;
  System.debug('SIZEEE'+reportList.size()); // I can see this this in logs
  System.debug('Constructor is working!!'); // I can see this this in logs
}

global List<Report__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{ 
   System.debug('Is it returning the BatchList?!'); // I CANT see this in logs
   return this.batchList; 

}     

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Report__c> scope)
{
    insert scope;
    System.debug('Executing insert!!'); // I CANT see this in logs
}     

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{     
} 

}
```

I'm not able to insert records using this. Please let me know what needs to be done in order to insert records using Batch class.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What volume of `Report__c` objects are you passing in? Do you see any `BatchSerialChunkHandler` type logs in your Developer Console when you do this? What do those logs say, or the Apex Jobs list in Setup?

Comment: Hello @DavidReed, currently the reportList.size() is just 25. Also, I don't see any BatchSerialChunkHandler type logs.

Comment: When you look at the Apex Jobs list in Setup, do you see this batch job and what is its status? If you invoke it from Anonymous Apex, what log entries appear? One possibility is that `Report__c` includes non-serializable member variables.

Comment: @DavidReed I don't see any error in the log entries. Also, I'm able to insert the same Report__c list with my current class. Hence I was wondering if something is wrong with my Batch class or the way I'm calling the Database.executeBatch(b); in the current class. Please let me know if there are any suggestions :)

Comment: Make sure you're checking *all* the logs; there should be four in total: however you called the method, one for the start method, one for the execute method, and one for the finish method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a batch class with a state, but without the right interface. You need to add the `Database.Stateful` interface to your class. It doesn't require any additional methods, but lets the system running the code know that you have additional variables in your class, which need to be maintained between each run. As soon as you hit `start`, your variable will be empty, and nothing with happen (maybe a null pointer exception).

Your example is pretty much a perfect example of when to use the interface. Basic rule of thumb is if you're using a constructor, you'll need to set the interface to keep any variables set inside it between runs. If your code is just passing records from the `start` method, and has no class variables, you're probably okay. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) (about halfway down the page) for more info.